# Как определить листинг-файлов в ответе сервера по CURL-запросу из PHP?

Tags: php, apache, curl

Делаю CURL-запрос в PHP по определенному адресу (каталогу) на сайте, к примеру: 
http://site.com/folder

Как мне в CURL-запросе однозначно понять, что сервер вернул именно листинг файлов и папок (при включенной опции Options +Indexes), а не пустую страницу или Forbiden?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста в вопрос фрагмент кода, как вы делаете запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Курлом смотреть заголовки:
если "http 200 ok" то гуд,
смотрим Content-Length - если больше N то совсем прекрасно

Answer (score 1):

1. В самом простом варианте, проверить что **title** и **h1** совпадает с
   **Index of /**:

   ```
   if (preg_match('!<title>Index of /!i', $body) && preg_match('!<h1>Index of /!i', $body)) {
       // это дефолтная страница apache со списком файлов
   }
   ```
2. Так же дополнительно можно проверять, что страница не содержит
   "левых тегов", таких как `<div><span><header><h2...h5><script>`.
   Если содержит, значит это не листинг файлов.

[image: Apache листинг файлов]